# Change existing Netbeans C++ project to Qt Application

Tags: c++, qt, netbeans

I have an existing Netbeans C++ project I want to change to a Netbeans Qt- Application. Is there an easy way to do it or do I have to reimport all my classes?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any way to change a netbeans project after it is created. I would just make a new Qt application project. Then you can right click on the project name and choose "add existing items from folders...". That will allow you to import a whole folder of code files at one time. I would copy all the code out of the old project folder and into the new project folder before adding them, so the project code is all at the same place. Hope this helps.